# Can't set InputScope of RichEditBox to "Text" in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, inputscope

In a Windows 8.1 app I'm not able to set the InputScope-property of the RichEditBox to "Text" although, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue), it should be possible.

The option is missing in the enumeration but I don't understand why.

I get the following error when setting `InputScope="Text"`:

> "Unable to convert 'Text' to the type 'InputScope'"

I'm using the following environment:

> Window 8.1 Pro
>
> Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate update 5
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.00081

In the properties of the project the application target is set to Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` input scope is **not** supported in `Windows Runtime` apps.

You can read about all the available input scopes in the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue), and you probably missed the **note** which says not supported in `Windows` apps.

I would suggest you use `Chat` or `Search` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

The weird thing is that my colleague can set InputScope="Text".
The only difference is that he has Windows 10 installed on his machine.